# Redirect using post and get the succes of the redirect

Tags: javascript, html, perl, redirect, post

Say, I have a simple form on my website having three fields : name, password and email.

1. I have to get these information from the users, and keep in my database.
2. Then redirect to another website and send all these information using **post**.
3. I also have to know whether the user was successfully redirected to that site(HTTP STATUS 200).

Here's how I'm doing it:

For Point 1, I'm simply submitting the form.

After the data has been successfully saved in my database, I'm rendering the following form with hidden fields. This gets submitted and user gets redirected to anotherwebsite.com

```
    <form id="form_id" action="https://www.anotherwebsite.com/form" method="POST">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="name" value ="$name">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="password" value ="$password">
    <input type ="hidden" name ="email" value ="$email">
    </form>
    <script> document.getElementById('form_id').submit();  </script>
```

**Problems**:

1. I don't think my strategy to achieve point 1 and 2 is correct. I need a better solution. Submitting the form, then rendering a page with hidden fields and submitting it again to redirect to another site just doesn't feel right.
2. I have no clue to achieve the 3rd point.

Comment: There's no way to tell what happens after the form is submitted. It reloads the page and your scripts stop running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you might try this approach:

1. create a form with name, password, email fields in a file ( HTML ).
2. Submit the form to server.
3. On the server side get the data (including the form attribute in a variable) and save it to database.
4. then redirect to the given website ( using the variable you've stored in step 3 ).

You can easily know the status ( 202 or any error) using any of server side scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve point 3 you need to use cookies if you are actually trying to implement a login-cum-membersarea system. Othewise, you simple need a redirect inside a condition statement.

```
my $cgi = CGI->new; 
if (condition) { print $cgi->redirect('https://www.examplesite.com/file.html') }
```

for a general way of doing point 1-2, you can look at the tutorial here:
http://practicalperl5.blogspot.com/

Comment: If the user is being redirected to another site (not just another page on the same site), cookies won't work for #3 because cookies are site-specific. Unless a browser has a _serious_ security flaw, it will never send cookies to any site other than the site which set them.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it. But I figured for someone who wasn't able to implement a html form and pass values via cgi to a backend script, even though he wrote "another site" .. he may as well as a whole is trying to implement a login-membershiparea system. But I guess I will edit the answer for both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the user to another website, the only way to know that the user was successfully redirected is for that website to notify you in some manner.  Once the user leaves your page (and that's what a redirect is - it tells the browser "leave this URI and go to this URI instead"), the scripts on that page stop running, so they can't collect any further information.

If you just need to know that the information was submitted successfully, your script could POST the data in the background, wait for a 200 response, *then* redirect after the information has been submitted.  But that may not meet your requirements, since you still won't know if the redirect succeeded.

Another possibility which *does* allow you to know whether the page on the other site loaded correctly would be to open it in a new browser window/tab instead of redirecting.  This is the only way to keep your page active (and, thus, your scripts able to run) while loading another page.  However, it introduces other issues, like what to do with the original page.  (Leave it open in the background (likely to confuse the user) or close itself after seeing that the new URI has loaded (could cause undesirable visual artifacts as one window/tab opens and then the original one closes; destroys browser history)?)

If at all possible, having the final destination site notify you when the transaction completes is almost certainly the best way to go.